# ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined, a V8 version problem?

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc, mysql-workbench

My code has been working daily for 6 months and it appears it doesn't work anymore. I know Google App Script Runtime did an update to V8 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime (message displayed when I open "Script editor"). I suspect the problem comes from this version change because nothing else has changed.

I use Jdbc to access an SQL database at the beginning of the code:

```
  var connectionName = '';
  var user = '';
  var userPwd = '';
  var db = '';
  var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://'+connectionName+'/'+db;
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
```

The error message I get is "ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined", and I don't know how to fix it.

Could someone have a solution please?

Comment: The [Google issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149273194) now says that the issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue with v8 and Google has acknowledged the bug. You may follow the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149273194#comment2) for updates.

Comment: Hello,
The issue seemed solved but this "Jdbc" problem occured again. I still follow the instructions but it doesn't work anymore. An other update changed method to use Jdbc? Someone has an idea?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The [Google issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149273194) now says that the issue has been fixed

---

##### Original answer (obsolete)

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60237768) is correct, here is some additional information and a possible workaround. As noted in [a comment on the issue on the Google issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/149273194#comment52), you can pass `Jdbc` from the script using the library to a function in the library to make this work.

Example in the library `Lib`:

```
function getConnection(tjdbc) {
  //dbUrl = ...
  //user = ...
  //password = ...
  return tjdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, password);
}
```

in the script using the library :

```
function doStuff() {
  var connection = Lib.getConnection(Jdbc);
  //... 
}
```

As the database can be queried using the resulting [JdbcConnection](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc/jdbc-connection), this might be the only place where you need to pass `Jdbc` in this way. It seems however that under V8 accessing Databases using `Jdbc` is also much slower than under Rhino (by a factor of 800 in my tests), so be warned.

Comment: Thanks, the workaround is currently valid. With my Update SQL:  Rhino and V8 ran at almost same time.

Comment: That is working, thanks, But I have created a script with another gmail account and deployed with library, and I am accessing that library in another Gmail account to perform database query, The Jdbc library is working with same Gmail account, but when I access that library with another Gmail account than Jdbc giving reference error, can you help out in this?

Comment: @AmitKumar sorry for the late reply. Maybe you would be interested to know that the issue is now fixed